# How to Bring javascript Popup in Gridview selected index?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

Open popup window on grid view selected index. The code work's fine but it bring a new tab I need a pop window

```
protected void gvUsrlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Write(@"<script language=""javascript"">window.open('MyCustm.aspx');</script>");
```

or

```
Response.Write(@"<script language=""javascript"">var myOpenedWindow = myOpenedWindow || window.open('MyCustm.aspx', '');</script>");
```

proper solution needed in java script if possible

Comment: just stop Checking my grammar Please Provide me a Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters to window.open in doing this **MOST browsers** will pop open in new window instead of adding another tab.

[W3 Schools Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)

Example:

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "thisIsMyWindowName", "height=200,width=200");
```

if you do not want to specify window height and width just pass specs as a blank string.

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "thisIsMyWindowName", "");
```